# Docusign accesstoken to send envelope from nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, access-token

Is there option to automatically retrieve access token in nodejs to send envelope to people ,from developer account. Or how should i do it properly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote "automatically" I assume you mean that you want to do that without asking the end-user to login to DocuSign.
This is possible with [JWT Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), which is one option for authentication with the DocuSign APIs.

Doing it from Node.JS with the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusign-esign) is pretty simple but you'll need to configure a few things, or you can use [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/).

The [Node.JS code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/DSJwtAuth.js) to obtain access token use JWT with the Note.js SDK:

```
const jwtLifeSec = 10 * 60, // requested lifetime for the JWT is 10 min
    dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();
dsApi.setOAuthBasePath(dsConfig.dsOauthServer.replace('https://', '')); // it should be domain only.
const results = await dsApi.requestJWTUserToken(dsConfig.dsClientId,
    dsConfig.impersonatedUserGuid, this.scopes, rsaKey,
    jwtLifeSec);

const expiresAt = moment().add(results.body.expires_in, 's').subtract(tokenReplaceMin, 'm');
this.accessToken = results.body.access_token;
```

**Note:** you'll need [consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/) of user, this is required only once.

Comment: For individual consent, see the new [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBziZ2TfFVs&t=7s)